# Building a comparative rater with MS Access Web App

Tags: ms-access

To start, I am pretty new to Access but have already built the basic frame work for my database and it is currently operational. I have reached a few sticking points that I was wondering if someone would be able to help me out on.

I am building a comparative rater for my business loan brokerage so my reps can perform a form query with the customers vitals which would then return a list of lenders that match those parameters.

In quite a few cases I have multiple values for the same category. For example, each Lender in our network operates in different states and I need to be able to run my query based in part by which states they can operate. "Lender A = CA, FL, MN" ect.. I thought I had my problem solved when I found multi-valued fields but alas they are not usable in the Access app version for Sharepoint. I am sure there is a basic way I can do this through the Access app for share point but search as I might it escapes me.

My question is mainly how I would structure a table to allow for multiple values in a single field like in the example above. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you building this from the start as a web database? This setup will prevent you from using such multi-value fields anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multivalue fields, they may be useful for very simple applications only. Just implement many-to-many relation using 3 tables: `Lenders`, `Operates` and `States`. `Operates` contains references to `Lenders` and `States`. Internally multivalue fields implemented using the same way, two additional tables are hidden.